# How can I make a command in java execute only once?

Tags: java

I'm a complete beginner at Java and right now I'm trying to learn more about switch/class/loops and I have this code:

```
boolean loop = true;
while (loop) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean executed = true;

    if (!executed) {
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter a command: ");
        executed = true;
    }

    String text = input.nextLine();

    switch (text) {

        case "start":
            System.out.println("\nYou began playing");
            text = input.nextLine();
            //loop = false;

        case "stop":
            System.out.println("\nYou stopped playing");
            text = input.nextLine();

    }
}
```

My problem is that I am trying to have this line: `System.out.println("\nPlease enter a command: ");` only run once, how do I do that?

When I type "start", I get the start message, and when I type "stop", I get the stop message. But if I type "start" or "stop" a second time, it jumps to the "please enter a command" message.

How do I change the code so that it doesn't run the first message the second or third time I type in "start" or "stop"?

I took someone's advice and added this:

```
if (!executed) {
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter a command: ");
    executed = true;
}
```

But this doesn't work, it only results in the first message not showing up at all, when the program starts...

Comment: You need to move `executed` out of the loop.

Comment: `boolean executed = true;` followed by `if(!executed)` - can't see how that would work

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to just move the print statement outside the loop? It would also increase readability imo.

Comment: You forgot to add `break` statements to your `case`s. In this case, if one enters "start", both start and stop cases are executed.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Check

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean executed = true;

if(!executed) {
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter a command: ");
    executed = true;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if(!true) {
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter a command: ");
    executed = true;
}
```

So the statement will never enter.
You have to put your variable outside of the while loop and set it to false.

```
boolean executed = false;
while(loop) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    if(!executed) {
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter a command: ");
        executed = true;
    }

    //...
}
```

But your problem is, that you never leave the while loop after "stop" .

Additionally you forgot the break after each switch statement. That cause in a continue with the next switch statement.

Better write

```
boolean loop = true;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while(loop) {
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter a command: ");
    String text = input.nextLine();

    switch (text) {

    case "start":
        System.out.println("\nYou began playing");
        break;

    case "stop":
        System.out.println("\nYou stopped playing");

        loop = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you really want to call the "Please enter a command" only once put it outside of the while loop.

Comment: you never stop the loop though

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your code by a lot, as currently you have some major flaws in it.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");

outer: for(String text = input.nextLine(); ; text = input.nextLine()) {   
    switch (text) {    
        case "start":
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("You began playing");
            break;
        case "stop":
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("You stopped playing");
            break outer; // break the for-loop
        default: 
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

1. You can move the line `System.out.println("\nPlease enter a command: ");` out of the loop.
2. You can replace every `System.out.println("\nSome message")` with just two calls to `System.out.println()` one is empty one has the message.
3. You probably want to `break` in your switch statements. Because else they will *fall-through*, leading to not intended behaviour.
4. You also want to add a `default` branch in your `switch` to handle cases when `text` will not be equal to `"start"` nor `"stop"`.

Comment: I think 2. is just a matter of opinion. I myself prefer `\nSomeText` others may not. I wouldn't brand it an 'improvement'.

Comment: @L.Spillner well `\n` may not work on every os, because some use different line seperators. so my recommended variant is the best bet to work on every plattform

Comment: Mhm I can live with that explanation. Still the OS not following such a common convention should rethink their developing strategy ;)

Comment: @L.Spillner I agree with that. I use `\n` all over the place, even when on Windows. They should drop the carriage return alltogether.

Comment: This helped a lot. I also changed so that after case "stop": it says 'break;' instead of 'break outer;' , so that i can type stop and start again and again if i want to

Comment: @J.Lars Glad I could help :)